# Implement app able to receive push notifications and launch web browser

Tags: android, ios, windows-phone-7, blackberry, push-notification

What is the easiest way to implement a simple app which does two things:

- receive push notifications (new messages in user's inbox),
- open a page on my website in a webview or web browser.

It would be best if the solution was portable among iOS, Android and possibly other mobile systems like Windows Phone and BlackBerry 10, but I'm happy with separate solutions, if it's the only way to do it.

Comment: why would you expect to gain access to native services such as APNS from the web browser?  Just write a full blown app and skip all of this mess.

Comment: It could be a native app with a webview and nothing else. Is there anything wrong with this approach? Right now I just don't have resources to develop full blown apps for major systems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are solutions like http://xtify.com/ or http://urbanairship.com/products/push-notifications/ that provide an all in one package across platforms but I don't know the quality of service or which one would be right for you, some research on your part will be necessary if you choose this path.

Or you could implement it yourself but it will require your own server. The server would notify both Androids C2DM And Apple Push Service at the same time. You will have to implement the client side on each.

For iPhone here's a good tutorial for setting it up http://www.raywenderlich.com/3443/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-12

For Android http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidCloudToDeviceMessaging/article.html

You register your app with both services then sends the push keys to your server. With the keys the server can then notify both platforms respective push services to send a notification .

I can't really help with the server setup stuff as its not my area of expertise but this is how we implement push notifications for the apps my company makes.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest that, checking out [Parse](https://www.parse.com/) apis for this task.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend a Phonegap (Cordova) app and UrbanAirship for the notifications.  You can get a free account with that.  It's relatively easy to implement too.

As for the browser, I'm not sure exactly what you want it for. Could you elaborate and I'll post a response.

Comment: Well, I want the webrowser to open a page on my website. I don't want to develop a full blown app for iOS, Android, etc., but I like the push notifications. If the user gets a message from another user of my site I want him to receive a standard system notification on his device and be able to open the page after touching it.

Comment: Yes UrbanAirship's API would allow this.  Read the docs about phonegap apps with UrbanAirship.  In terms of the webpage, I would use something like an iFrame.